# Threading matplotlib for multiple subplots

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I am never used the threading and would like to know if it is possible to thread plots for matplotlib. When you have a large dataset for matplotlib it becomes very slow to generate graphs. I tried writing code to thread the process below but it does display a graph

```
from pylab import *
import threading
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gp1(aa):
    fig=plt.figure()
    ax1=plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
    aa['a'].hist(color='g')
    aa['b'].hist(color='b')
def gp2 (bb):
    ax2=plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=3)
    bb['c'].hist(color='r')
    bb['d'].hist(color='y')

def gp3(cc):
    ax3=plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2,0), colspan=3)
    cc['a'].hist(color='b')
    cc['c'].hist(color='r')



def graph(aa):
    a = threading.Thread(target=gp1, args=aa)
    b = threading.Thread(target=gp2, args=aa)
    c = threading.Thread(target=gp3, args=aa)

    a.start()
    b.start()
    c.start()
    plt.show()


df = pd.DataFrame(randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

graph(df)
```

few questions I have are will this make plotting faster? and is there a good places to learn threading by showing examples other than stackoverflow and [pymotw](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/index.html#module-threading)?

Comment: In general the backends don't play very nice with threading.  It can be done (I think, but might require heroic coding), but probably isn't worth the hassle.  Have you profiled your code?  Are you sure mpl is the bottle neck?  Are you re-using figures/axes?  There are a bunch of low-hanging fruit that can help which does not require the complication of threads.

Comment: @tcaswell I never used threading or multiprocessing before and just wanted to know how to properly use it with code.